# Should i check if logged in before every frontend action

Tags: reactjs, express, authentication, session

I have a React Frontend end Express with Passport in the Backend. My Login Session works, i also have authenticated backend Routes. Now the question is, in my frontend i sometimes want to know if i am logged in. For example to show a button that's only there if i am logged in.

Currently i call a database request which returns if i am logged in or not every time to determine that.

```
async function isLoggedIn() {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/loggedin', {
        credentials: 'include',
    });
    let loggedInJson = await response.json();
    const loggedIn = loggedInJson.loggedIn;
    return loggedIn;
}
```

Is this good practice? Or would it be better to try to access if a login cookie exists (which i wouldn't know how to do).

My question number 2 would be what a good way to store that login status would be.

I thought about using reducer for handling the login status (a bit complex tho)

Comment: it's a good practise to save the user permissions in the client. You can assume the stored permissions are valid and render accordingly meanwhile checking in the background if the user is indeed authenticated. Since all actions are validated on the server there's little harm in showing the wrong ui for a short while. See JWT for a seamless way of doing this. Access tokens are best stored in secure http-only cookies to avoid token sniffing.

Comment: Since i'm using the standard cookie from express and passsport in the background. Does that mean i could/should create a cookie just for storing the login status?